# Is there a way to connect with Python to Azure when you don't want a prompt nor a service principal?

Tags: python, bash, azure, authentication, azure-cli

I would like to connect to Azure in a Python script.

When I do that:

```
from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
credentials, subscription = get_azure_cli_credentials()
```

I have this error:

```
CLIError: 
Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

By launching "az login", I have a window opening. I don't want that.

I can't find a way to authenticate to Azure without windows prompting nor service principal that works. Does anyone know what to do?

I didn't find any solution with Bash either.

Comment: Run `az login`, it will save your authentication details, so you don't need to do it after.

Comment: I want to do it only with python or bash. With az login, as i have a 2 authentication factors, a graphical window opens. I dont want it. Sorry, but using az login doesnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the Rest API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api). Here a solution in Python:

```
import requests

#Get the token
data_for_token_request = {'grant_type':'client_credentials','resource':'https://management.core.windows.net/', 'client_id':'<you-client-id>', 'client_secret':'<your-client-secret>'}
token_response = requests.post(
   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant>/oauth2/token',
    data=data_for_token_request).\
    json()

token= token_response['access_token']


#List all the files in each model
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}

contentFile = requests.get("https://<your-datalake-name>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/<path-to-your-file>?op=OPEN",headers=headers)

with open("demofile.txt", "w") as f:
     f.write(contentFile.text())

f.close()
```